# Div element rises when content is added

Tags: html, css

I have a main wrapper div with some inline-block content divs within. For some reason when my bottom right content div is empty it is in a lowered position, then when I add a button and input element to it it rises to the correct position I want it in. This behavior is really puzzling to me, I've recreated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ywbyLdcn/3/, just remove the content of the inner div of 'outer4' div and see it lower.

I have a feeling this is happening because one of the elements (button) inserted has padding on it, but I'm not sure:

```
button {
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Can anyone please help me figure out why this is happening? Note I actually want it in the raised position, when it's empty it is out of line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick solution to this is to add the following rule:

```
#wrap div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

This selects all `div` within your `#wrap` and makes them align to the top, instead of the default "baseline". Read more about `vertical-align`, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ywbyLdcn/4/)

Comment: Well that definitely fixes the lowered div issue, though I'm still curious why it's happening. Thankyou

Comment: @MarksCode, because unless you define `vertical-align` it will take the default value of `baseline`. That pushes it down.

Comment: Ok, so how come it rises when content is added?

Comment: @MarksCode because the baseline changes. I believe it was initially only intended for text (baseline is the imaginary line the text "rests" on, or the line you'd write on on a lined wordpad). It is a bit of a mystery how it works in the background; for me anyways.